# trouble parsing json string

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse this simple json string:

```
var dataJSON = {};
    var data;

            dataJSON = {
            "status": "OK", 
            "messages" : [{
                "user" : {
                    "id" : "4",
                    "status" : "offline",
                    "name" : "dummy",
                    "pictures" : ["pic.jpg"]
                },
                "message" : "Hey",
                "timestamp" : 1395660658
            }, {
                "user" : {
                    "id" : "2",
                    "status" : "online",
                    "name" : "dummy1",
                    "pictures" : ["pic1.jpg"]
                },
                "message" : "hello",
                "timestamp" : 1395660658
            }]
        };

        console.log('test');
        console.log(dataJSON);

        //parse data
        data = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
```

but I am getting the following error:

"unable to parse json string"

I have mo idea why, cheers.

Comment: That is not even a JSON string.

Comment: @user: JSON is a text notation used for transferring data between environments. What is your need for JSON here? If the data is only to be used in a program, then you use the notation for creating data structures appropriate for the programming language, in this case JavaScript.

Comment: Derek it passes a JSON validator, cookie monster - I need it for unit testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to parse it at all; it's a JavaScript object already.

The acronym "JSON"  stands for  **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. It's a restricted form of the native syntax in JavaScript for creating objects "on the fly".  To say that another way, JavaScript's native object literal syntax is a superset of JSON.  What you've typed in there, as the value of your "dataJSON" variable, is a JavaScript object literal expression. The value of such an expression is a reference to an object. No parsing necessary, since the JavaScript parser itself has already done so.

*edit* — if you really do need a JSON string for testing purposes, then I think the easiest way to do that is to use `JSON.stringify()` to convert an object into a string, and then pass it into the test code. In your example, that'd look like:

```
    dataJSON = JSON.stringify({
        "status": "OK", 
        "messages" : [{
            "user" : {
                "id" : "4",
                "status" : "offline",
                "name" : "dummy",
                "pictures" : ["pic.jpg"]
            },
            "message" : "Hey",
            "timestamp" : 1395660658
        }, {
            "user" : {
                "id" : "2",
                "status" : "online",
                "name" : "dummy1",
                "pictures" : ["pic1.jpg"]
            },
            "message" : "hello",
            "timestamp" : 1395660658
        }]
    });
```

It's a little easier than trying to construct the string by hand because of the "quote quoting" nuisance. Of course the object you pass in should be one that actually can be represented as JSON, but your sample above is definitely OK.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, then why is it when say I make an API call and it responds this string I will have to parse it?

Comment: @user3754111 because that's a totally different situation. If you communicate with a server and it responds with a string, then it has to be parsed. That's really the point of JSON - it's for data on the wire. If you're just declaring an object directly in your code, then there's no JSON parsing involved, just JavaScript.

Comment: @user3754111 If you need to do unit testing with JSON strings, then I'll add something to the answer.

Comment: "because that's a totally different situation. If you communicate with a server and it responds with a string, then it has to be parsed. That's really the point of JSON - it's for data on the wire. If you're just declaring an object directly in your code," - so if I write the json string and put it in a simple string variable does that mean I can parse it?

Comment: @user3754111 yes - like I wrote in the update to the answer, it can be somewhat painful to type in a JSON string because you run into the problem of having to include quotes in a quoted string. That's why I suggested creating a plain JavaScript object and using `JSON.stringify()` to turn it into a string that you'll in turn use for testing. It's just a suggestion.